# proxies do not render HTTPS pages with javascript correctly

Tags: tls, javascript, http-proxy

In technical terms, how come all proxies fail to display https pages (e.g. Facebook) correctly? The use of javascript is almost always disabled. The problem is in https? Can someone technically explain why there is always this problem?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you're asking here, but it could be something like CSP preventing Javascript connecting back to servers which aren't defined in the page itself.

Comment: This seems more like a config issue rather than some common problem.

Comment: no it is not a configuration problem , all proxy https online ( for example https://hide.me/en/proxy ) 
does not permit the correct display of https pages , why? the problem is in https protocol that block this process?

Comment: it might help if you described what "not correctly" means

Comment: If you mean a proxy that is designed to hide your identity, then it is a feature, not a bug, to disable javascript. It is a measure to try to hide your identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a proxy, the ability of the server to prove its identity to your browser is broken.  You can override this by the "confirm security exception" dialogs in your browser.  I'm sure everyone reading this has had to do this at some point.  So, you in effect told your browser to accept the identity of the main site (for example https://www.facebook.com) through the proxy but Facebook and other sites load Javascripts from many different sources.  So, in addition to https://www.facebook.com, you would need to let your browser know that, for example, "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net" is OK to load through the proxy as well.  This is your browser trying to protect you from visiting a site that is pretending to be Facebook or https://static.xx.fbcdn.net without providing the ssl/tls certificate.  By using a proxy, you are shedding this protection.

Comment: there is a way to tell the browser to allow all links javascript through proxy ?